# Installing virtualenv for Python2.7

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have installation of python 2.7 and 3.3 side by side (C:\Python27 and C:\Python33). I am now trying to install virtualenv.

Python2.7 is my default interpreter. Whenever I open a command prompt and type 'python' it brings up "Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:40:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32" for me. But when I am firing "pip install virtualenv", it is installing virtualenv inside python3.3 folder.

I am quite surprised that my active interpreter is python2.7, but virtualenv installation is somehow getting inside python3.3 folder instead of expected python2.7 folder. Can anyone please explain this anomaly and suggest me how to install virtualenv inside python 2.7 ?

Comment: Try `pip2.7 install virtualenv`.

Comment: That didnt work..."'pip2.7' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd imagine your environment variables are set up to use the python2.7 environment variable for `python` and the path to the python3.3 `pip` for that, you either need to adjust those or use the full paths when using the tool as you require.